# I am having issues getting selected value from a jquery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have two input tags and two select dropdown tags, so I want the input value and the selected value from the dropdown to always update(onchange and keyup) on a result span on the same page. It's a currency converter project.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var baseCurrency = "BTC";
      var pay_amount = 1;
      var targetCurrency = "ETH";
      var get_amount;
      $("#crypto12").html(targetCurrency);
      $("#crypto14").html(targetCurrency);
      $("#crypto16").html(targetCurrency);
      $("#crypto13").html(baseCurrency);
      $("#crypto15").html(baseCurrency);
      $("#crypto17").html(baseCurrency);
      $("#crypto19").html(targetCurrency);
       var url;
       currencyConverter(baseCurrency, pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount)
       
        // some variables
        $("#crypto1").ddslick({
          imagePosition: "left",
          selectText: "BTC",
          onSelected: function (data) {
            $("#selected").html((baseCurrency = data.selectedData.value));
            currencyConverter(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
          },
        });

        $("#crypto2").ddslick({
          imagePosition: "left",
          selectText: "ETH",
          onSelected: function (data) {
            $("#selected").html((targetCurrency = data.selectedData.value));
           currencyConverter2(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
          },
        });

       // currencyConverter(baseCurrency, pay_amount, targetCurrency, get_amount);

        // get base currency value

        $("#crypto1").change(function () {
          // base currency

          baseCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

          // call currencyConverter function
          currencyConverter(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
        });

        // get base currency number

        $("#pay_amount").keyup(function () {
          // base number

          pay_amount = $(this).val();

          // call currencyConverter function

          currencyConverter(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
        });

        // get target currency value

        $("#crypto2").change(function () {
          // target currency

         targetCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                   
          // call currencyConverter function

          currencyConverter2(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
        });

        // get target currency number

        $("#get_amount").keyup(function () {
          // target number

          get_amount = $(this).val();

          // call currencyConverter function

          currencyConverter2(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
        });
        
        
        function currencyConverter(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount) {
          // api url

          var url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref=" + targetCurrency + "&symbol=" + baseCurrency;
           

          // make a get request to API

          $.get(url, function (data) {
            console.log(data.price)

            //for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.price)) {
            //console.log(data.price);
            var result = parseFloat(data.price * pay_amount).toFixed(4);

            var divobj = document.getElementById("get_amount");
            divobj.value = result;

            $("#get_amount").html($("#get_amount").val());
            $("#crypto12").html(targetCurrency);
            $("#crypto14").html(targetCurrency);
            $("#crypto16").html(targetCurrency);
            $("#crypto19").html(targetCurrency);            
            $("#crypto16")
              .parent()
              .find("#result")
              .html($("#get_amount").val());
              
              $("#crypto14")
              .parent()
              .find("#result")
              .html($("#get_amount").val());
           // }
            //console.log(`data.price.${targetCurrency}`)
          });
        }
        //currencyConverter(baseCurrency, pay_amount, targetCurrency, get_amount);
         
        function currencyConverter2(baseCurrency, pay_amount, targetCurrency, get_amount) {
          // api url

          var url = "https://coinlib.io/api/v1/coin?key=659b81f02b22b218&pref=" + baseCurrency + "&symbol=" + targetCurrency;

          // make a get request to API

          $.get(url, function (data) {
            console.log(data.price)

            for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data.price)) {
             // console.log(value)

              var result = parseFloat(data.price * get_amount).toFixed(4);
              var divobj = document.getElementById("pay_amount");
              divobj.value = result;
              
            $("#pay_amount").html($("#pay_amount").val());
            $("#crypto13").html(baseCurrency);
            $("#crypto15").html(baseCurrency);
            $("#crypto17").html(baseCurrency);
            $("#crypto17")
              .parent()
              .find("#result")
              .html($("#pay_amount").val());
              
               $("#crypto15")
              .parent()
              .find("#result")
              .html($("#pay_amount").val());
            }
            //console.log(`data.price.${targetCurrency}`)
          });
        }
        //currencyConverter(baseCurrency, pay_amount, targetCurrency, get_amount);
      });
```

Here is the complete code [at JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kathrynbow/gk64Lcts/7/).

Comment: Seems to be working?

Comment: is not working the target currency is working but the base currency is not working, same with pay amount, and get amount, they should update on keyup or onchange

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I can't say that the logic is correct in terms of converting. I am getting 1 BTC is worth 32 LTC.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by changing the id names to match the html.

HTML

```
<select name="" id="slick">
        <option
          value="BTC"
          data-description="Bitcoin"
          data-imagesrc="https://app.coinloan.io/app/img/ic_btc.c39a5bf.svg"
          >BTC</option
        >
```

Previous Code

```
$("#crytpo1").change(function () {
          // base currency
          baseCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

          // call currencyConverter function
          currencyConverter(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
        });
```

My change

```
$("#slick").change(function () {
          // base currency
          baseCurrency = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

          // call currencyConverter function  
        currencyConverter(baseCurrency,pay_amount,targetCurrency,get_amount );
        });
```